# WebGL 2.0 Error : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, webgl

I have studying to WebGL technical. Unfortunately I met some error. I want to draw 2D two shape for helicopter. I wrote code below. Exactly what I would like to do is to make a propeller on a shape called a body.

Note that I tried to create a new buffer and bind it, but it still failed. I do not think stride has been understood yet, but I want to learn how to solve it even if it is simple.

```js
// Vertex shader
var _vertexShader = `
    attribute vec4 _position;
    void main() {
        gl_Position = _position;
    }
`

// Fragment shader
var _fragmentShader = `
    precision mediump float;

    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 1);
    }
`

// Create shader
function createShader(gl, type, source) {
    var shader = gl.createShader(type)
    gl.shaderSource(shader, source)
    gl.compileShader(shader)
    var success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)
    if (success) {
        return shader
    } else {
        console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader))
        gl.deleteShader(shader)
        // return false
    }
}

// Linking shader by program
function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
    var program = gl.createProgram()
    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader)
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader)
    gl.linkProgram(program)
    var success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)
    if (success) {
        return program
    } else {
        console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program))
        gl.deleteProgram(program)
        // return false
    }
}

function main() {
    // Get a WebGL context.
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2')
    if (!gl) {
        alert('Not support.')
        return false
    }

    // Get the strings for our GLSL shaders.
    var vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, _vertexShader)
    var fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, _fragmentShader)
    // Link the two shaders into a program.
    var program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader)
    // Look up where the vertex data need to go.
    var positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, '_position')
    // Create a buffer and put the three 2d clip space points in it.
    var body_positionBuf = gl.createBuffer()
    // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = body_positionBuf).
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_positionBuf)
    var body_positions = new Float32Array(
        [
            // Body triangle (Right)
            -0.25,  0,
            0.25,  0,
            0, 0.5,
            // Body triangle (Left) 
            -0.15, 0,
            0.15, 0,
            0.15, -0.25,
            // Body square
            -0.15, 0,
            -0.15, -0.25,
            0.15, -0.25,
        ]   
    )

    var roter_positions = new Float32Array([
        0.15, 0.1,
        0.15, -0.1,
        -0.15, 0.1,

        -0.15, -0.1,
        -0.15, 0.1,
        0.15, 0.1,
    ])

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
    // Code above this line is initialization code.
    // Code below this line is rendering code.

    // webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas)
    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels.
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height)

    // Clear the canvas.
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    
    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders).
    gl.useProgram(program)
    // Turn on the attribute.
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc)
    // Bind the position buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_positionBuf)

    // Tell the attribute how to get data out of body_positionBuf (ARRAY_BUFFER).
    var size = 2
    var type = gl.FLOAT
    var normalize = false
    var stride = 0
    var offset = 0 
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, size, type, normalize, stride, offset)
    // Draw.
    var drawType = gl.TRIANGLES
    var count = body_positions.length / 2
    gl.drawArrays(drawType, offset, count)
}

main()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```

How can i do? I don't know.. Please help me thanks.

Comment: You have to create a 2nd buffer. When you want to draw then you have to bind the buffer `gl.bindBuffer`, define the vertex attribute `gl.vertexAttribPointer` and finally the to do the draw call `gl.drawArrays`. This 3 steps you have to do for both objects.

Comment: If you just want to use 1 buffer, then you have define a data store which is large enough for both arrays `gl.bufferData`. Add the data of both arrays to the buffer by `gl.bufferSubData`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks. I have some question. Vertex shader code is same..? Sorry.. I don’t understand..

Comment: @Rabbid76 May i see example some code..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all the vertices coordinates which are specified in `body_positions` cover the vertices specified in `roter_positions`.
Change the vertex coordinates:

```
var roter_positions = new Float32Array([
    0.15, 0.6,
    0.15, 0.4,
    -0.15, 0.6,

    -0.15, 0.4,
    -0.15, 0.6,
    0.15, 0.6,
])
```

Note, I recommend to use a model matrix, to define the position and orientation of each object individually. But solve your issue first and then take the next step.

If you wan to use 2 buffers, then you have to create 2 buffer objects and you have to define the data store of both objects:

```
var body_positionBuf = gl.createBuffer()
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_positionBuf)
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW)

var roter_positionBuf = gl.createBuffer()
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, roter_positionBuf)
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, roter_positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
```

Finally you can draw the meshes in the 2 separated buffers, by 2 separated draw calls. You have to define the array of generic vertex attribute data before each draw call:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_positionBuf)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)       
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, body_positions.length / 2)

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, roter_positionBuf)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)       
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, roter_positions.length / 2)
```

See the example, eher I applied the changes to your original code:

```js
// Vertex shader
var _vertexShader = `
    attribute vec4 _position;
    void main() {
        gl_Position = _position;
    }
`

// Fragment shader
var _fragmentShader = `
    precision mediump float;

    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 1);
    }
`

// Create shader
function createShader(gl, type, source) {
    var shader = gl.createShader(type)
    gl.shaderSource(shader, source)
    gl.compileShader(shader)
    var success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)
    if (success) {
        return shader
    } else {
        console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader))
        gl.deleteShader(shader)
        // return false
    }
}

// Linking shader by program
function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
    var program = gl.createProgram()
    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader)
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader)
    gl.linkProgram(program)
    var success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)
    if (success) {
        return program
    } else {
        console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program))
        gl.deleteProgram(program)
        // return false
    }
}

function main() {
    // Get a WebGL context.
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2')
    if (!gl) {
        alert('Not support.')
        return false
    }

    // Get the strings for our GLSL shaders.
    var vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, _vertexShader)
    var fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, _fragmentShader)
    // Link the two shaders into a program.
    var program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader)
    // Look up where the vertex data need to go.
    var positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, '_position')
    // Create a buffer and put the three 2d clip space points in it.
    
    var body_positions = new Float32Array(
        [
            // Body triangle (Right)
            -0.25,  0,
            0.25,  0,
            0, 0.5,
            // Body triangle (Left) 
            -0.15, 0,
            0.15, 0,
            0.15, -0.25,
            // Body square
            -0.15, 0,
            -0.15, -0.25,
            0.15, -0.25,
        ]   
    )

    var roter_positions = new Float32Array([
        0.15, 0.6,
        0.15, 0.4,
        -0.15, 0.6,

        -0.15, 0.4,
        -0.15, 0.6,
        0.15, 0.6,
    ])

    var body_positionBuf = gl.createBuffer()
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_positionBuf)
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW)

    var roter_positionBuf = gl.createBuffer()
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, roter_positionBuf)
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, roter_positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
    
    // webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas)
    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels.
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height)

    // Clear the canvas.
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    
    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders).
    gl.useProgram(program)
    // Turn on the attribute.
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc)
    // Bind the position buffer.
    
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_positionBuf)
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)       
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, body_positions.length / 2)

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, roter_positionBuf)
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)       
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, roter_positions.length / 2)
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```

---

Of course you can add the 2 arrays to 1 buffer. You have to create a buffer with a data store, which is large enough for both arrays. Add the data to the buffer by `gl.bufferData`:

```
var body_bytes = body_positions.length * 4;
var roter_bytes = roter_positions.length * 4;

var common_positionBuf = gl.createBuffer()
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, common_positionBuf)
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_bytes + roter_bytes, gl.STATIC_DRAW); 
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, body_positions);
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_bytes, roter_positions);
```

The mesh can be draw by a singel draw call:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, common_positionBuf)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0) 
var no_of_vertices = (body_positions.length + roter_positions.length) / 2      
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, no_of_vertices)
```

If some program resources would have to be changed, before the 2nd mesh is draw (e.g. model matrix uniform), then this can be done by 2 draw calls too:

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, body_positions.length / 2)

// change resources here ...

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, body_positions.length / 2, roter_positions.length / 2)
```

See the example, based on your original code from the question:

```js
// Vertex shader
var _vertexShader = `
    attribute vec4 _position;
    void main() {
        gl_Position = _position;
    }
`

// Fragment shader
var _fragmentShader = `
    precision mediump float;

    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 1);
    }
`

// Create shader
function createShader(gl, type, source) {
    var shader = gl.createShader(type)
    gl.shaderSource(shader, source)
    gl.compileShader(shader)
    var success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)
    if (success) {
        return shader
    } else {
        console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader))
        gl.deleteShader(shader)
        // return false
    }
}

// Linking shader by program
function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
    var program = gl.createProgram()
    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader)
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader)
    gl.linkProgram(program)
    var success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)
    if (success) {
        return program
    } else {
        console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program))
        gl.deleteProgram(program)
        // return false
    }
}

function main() {
    // Get a WebGL context.
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2')
    if (!gl) {
        alert('Not support.')
        return false
    }

    // Get the strings for our GLSL shaders.
    var vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, _vertexShader)
    var fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, _fragmentShader)
    // Link the two shaders into a program.
    var program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader)
    // Look up where the vertex data need to go.
    var positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, '_position')
    // Create a buffer and put the three 2d clip space points in it.
    
    var body_positions = new Float32Array(
        [
            // Body triangle (Right)
            -0.25,  0,
            0.25,  0,
            0, 0.5,
            // Body triangle (Left) 
            -0.15, 0,
            0.15, 0,
            0.15, -0.25,
            // Body square
            -0.15, 0,
            -0.15, -0.25,
            0.15, -0.25,
        ]   
    )

    var roter_positions = new Float32Array([
        0.15, 0.6,
        0.15, 0.4,
        -0.15, 0.6,

        -0.15, 0.4,
        -0.15, 0.6,
        0.15, 0.6,
    ])

    var body_bytes = body_positions.length * 4;
    var roter_bytes = roter_positions.length * 4;

    var common_positionBuf = gl.createBuffer()
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, common_positionBuf)
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_bytes + roter_bytes, gl.STATIC_DRAW); 
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, body_positions);
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, body_bytes, roter_positions);

    // webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas)
    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels.
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height)

    // Clear the canvas.
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    
    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders).
    gl.useProgram(program)
    // Turn on the attribute.
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc)
    // Bind the position buffer.
    
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, common_positionBuf)
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0) 
    var no_of_vertices = (body_positions.length + roter_positions.length) / 2      
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, no_of_vertices)
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```

Comment: Very Thanks! Now I have some understand for WebGL. There is one more question. So, when you draw shapes in WebGL, do you draw shapes like this?